# Qt: Program is crashing when deleting central widget of QMainWindow in destructor

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning Qt. Currently I stuck at layout stuff for `QMainWindow`. As suggested in some of examples available on internet i used `QWidget` to be used in `setCentralWidget(QWidget*)` method of QMainWindow. But as part of clean up when i am deleting central `QWidget` the program is crashing.

here is the code for .h

```
class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyMainWindow();

private:
    QVBoxLayout m_p1_level_vbox;
    QHBoxLayout m_p2_level_vbox;
    QHBoxLayout m_p2_level_hbox;
    QWidget* m_central_widget;
    QPushButton* m_increase_pressure;
    QPushButton* m_decrease_pressure;
};
```

for .cpp

```
MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , m_central_widget(new QWidget(this))
    , m_increase_pressure(new QPushButton("+", this))
    , m_decrease_pressure(new QPushButton("-", this))
{
    m_p2_level_hbox.addWidget(m_increase_pressure);
    m_p2_level_hbox.addWidget(m_decrease_pressure);

    m_p1_level_vbox.addLayout(&m_p2_level_hbox);

    m_central_widget->setLayout(&m_p1_level_vbox);
    setCentralWidget(m_central_widget);
}

MyMainWindow::~MyMainWindow()
{
    delete m_central_widget; // commenting this line doesn't  crash the program
    delete m_increase_pressure;
    delete m_decrease_pressure;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

In destructor if i don't delete `m_central_widget` then it works.

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: The childs widget will be deleted automatically when their parent is deleted. So you wouldn't delete the widget or the program crashed.

Comment: @tunglt but i am trying to follow the rule that every new should be balanced with delete. And Automatically by Qt?

Comment: @Swapnil Qt already follows that rule internally so you are trying to eliminate a pointer that has already been eliminated

Comment: The immediate cause of the problem, I believe, is that `m_increase_pressure` and `m_decrease_pressure` end up being owned by `m_central_widget`. When you `delete m_central_widget`, you also delete those two buttons, and then `delete m_increase_pressure` exhibits undefined behavior by way of double-destruction. Anyway, the advice in previous comments is correct - don't do manual deletion, allow Qt's ownership mechanism do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all learn and remember this [thing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject). If your object class has a QObject as a superclass then you should keep in mind that if you are deleting QObject, then you are deleting its children as well.

It is hidden, but truely cool mechanism.
For more information you are always welcome to read [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/). It is a little bit hard to understand, but sometimes helps with your issues much better than official documentation.

By the way, be ready to understand how do Layouts [work](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) in Qt .

Good luck in your Qt learning-journey ;)